# If I use a Mauritius passport to go from U.K. to Paris and then Paris to U.K. will I have problems getting back?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, uk-citizens

I am born in the U.K. if I bring my birth certificate is that good evidence that I’m from the uk. Either by Eurostar or flight

Comment: Note that Mauritian passport holders have visa-free access to the UK for up to 6 months, so even if you weren't in born the UK you'd likely still be allowed in.  (Same goes for the Schengen area.) The question is whether a UK citizen must present themselves as a UK citizen to UK border control.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you already asked? [Can I use a Mauritius passport to go from uk to paris and then Paris to uk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153742/can-i-use-a-mauritius-passport-to-go-from-uk-to-paris-and-then-paris-to-uk)

If you want further information, look under the second answer here, as @MichaelSeifert says you also have visa-free access to the UK under your Mauritius passport it matches your situation. [UK citizen without UK passport re-entering the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78669/uk-citizen-without-uk-passport-re-entering-the-uk)

Comment: The other question is about using visiting France and returning to the UK on a Mauritian passport, and OP was advised they should have proof of their UK citizenship. This question is about whether a British birth certificate is proof of UK citizenship. They're clearly very related and *could* very easily have been asked in one question, but they're also very clearly not the same question as each other.

Comment: I also think the advice about visa-free entry for citizens of Mauritius is misguided and could land OP in trouble. Citizens of Mauritius have time-limited visa-free entry for specific purposes which do not apply to OP.

Comment: Have you ever traveled outside the UK before? have you ever had a UK passport? (and if-so are you still in possesion of it, even if expired)

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

Birth in the UK does not automatically confer British citizenship (that's dependent on [various other circumstances, depending on your date of birth](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizenship)). As such, a UK birth certificate is not proof of UK citizenship. I don't recommend attempting to use it to enter the UK.

Some comments have suggested you needn't worry about proving British citizenship as Mauritian citizens can enter visa-free. I do not advise this route - that visa-free entry is for specific purposes (tourism, some types of short-term business/educational visits) which do not appear to apply to you.

Acquiring a British passport will make this trip much easier.

Comment: I am 19 years old if that makes a difference

Comment: @CarnaticHindustaniFusion it doesn't make a difference. The age thing only determines *which* set of criteria had to be fulfilled for you to have UK citizenship - but regardless of your age, your birth certificate doesn't show whether or not you fulfil those criteria.

Comment: AIUI if someone was born in the UK after the end of WW2, and before 1983 then the only way they would not be a British citizen is if their father was a foreign diplomat.